# Como simular um resultado baseado em uma dada probabilidade (ex: 8%) em javascript

Tags: javascript, random

Estou montando um simulador de resultado de jogo de futebol a partir de algumas variáveis.

A lógica é a seguinte:
A cada minuto ambos times tem uma probabilidade de fazer um gol. Essa probabilidade é calculada usando algumas variáveis como nota dos jogadores, tática usada, dentre outros.

Supondo que o Time A tem 8% de probabilidade de fazer um gol a cada minuto, como posso fazer para calcular essa probabilidade e retornar valores 1 para gol ou 0 para nenhum gol?

Algo assim:

```js
//VARIÁVEIS
var gol = 0;
var probabilidade = 0.8;
var tempo = 0;
var fimdejogo = 45;

//FUNÇÃO DE TEMPO E GOL
function TempoDeJogo() {
  while (tempo < fimdejogo) {
    tempo++;
    //FUNÇÃO DA PROBABILIDADE
    if (retorno_da_probabilidade == 1) {
      gol++;
      console.log(tempo, gol);
    }
  }
  console.log("Fim de Jogo");
}
TempoDeJogo();
```

Comment: `if (Math.random() <= probabilidade)` ... OBS: `0.8` é 80%, não 8%.

Comment: Show!!!, exatamente o que precisava, e valeu pela obs, dos 80% não tinha me tocado...rs